# How can I know how many files synced in desktop client software Resilio Sync?

Tags: resilio-sync

I know I can see how many files synced in mobile app about Resilio Sync by clicking the i icon near by a folder name.  You can see it at https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/206217345-How-to-link-my-mobile-device-to-my-desktop-computer-via-My-Devices and the following image.

But in desktop software of Resilio Sync such as Windows 7, I can't find a the i icon to display how many files in a folder are synced, how can I do ? Thans!

[image]

Comment: You can't; It appears the desktop version of the application doesn't have this feature

Comment: Thanks!  Which way can I know how many files synced in desktop client software?

Comment: If the client doesn't display it or there isn't an option to turn on that information on then the answer to your question is "you cannot"